# device not being recognized by DDMS or eclipse

Tags: android, apk, ddms, android-2.2-froyo

I have enabled USB debugging on my phone and have set the Debuggable permission in the AndroidManifest.xml to true. My devicce is not being shown in DDMS, Eclipse, or even the command prompt when I check for `adb devices`. I have also tried uninstalling/reinstalling my USB device drivers and restarting both my computer and my device. Nothing has worked so far. Has anyone run into or solved this problem before?

Comment: What Android device?  And what OS are you running?

Comment: @louielouie--my device is SGH-118 (Samsung Galaxy S) running Android 2.2. I'm running Eclipse on Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using windows you have to download usb drivers for that particular device

Comment: @HarshDevChandel--I've downloaded the USB drivers via the Android SDK Manager. Still I'm not able to get the device listed. Any other ideas?

Comment: you have to download the drivers from the company site search for usb drivers of that device by device name in the particular company device